# Вызвать Dispose у разных объектов

Tags: c#

Есть коллекция, которая содержит экземпляры объектов. Некоторые из них реализуют интерфейс `IDisposable`.

Вопрос, как в этой коллекции можно вызвать метод `Dispose`, у объектов, реализующих интерфейс?

Пробую так, но не получается увидеть `Dispose`:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    if (actTab is IDisposable)
    {
       // Вызвать Dispose         
    }
}
```

Comment: `actTab.Dispose()`?

Comment: @gil9red Почти) затупил, вопрос решён)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Чтобы вызвать метод `Dispose`, нужно привести `actTab` к `IDisposable`

Как один из вариантов решения:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    var disposableActTab = actTab as IDisposable;
    if (disposableActTab != null)
    {
        disposableActTab.Dispose();
    }
}
```

Он же с использованием null propagation:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    var disposableActTab = actTab as IDisposable;
    disposableActTab?.Dispose();
}
```

---

Если хочется оставить проверку с помощью `is`, то можно так:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    if (actTab is IDisposable)
    {
        ((IDisposable)actTab).Dispose();
    }
}
```

или так:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    if (actTab is IDisposable)
    {
        (actTab as IDisposable).Dispose();
    }
}
```

Начиная с C# 7.0 этот вариант можно записать короче с помощью [Type pattern](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/is#type), как показано [в ответе @trydex](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/892096/183458)

Answer (score 8):

Вы все правильно делаете, только чтобы метод `Dispose` был доступен нужно вызывать его через приведение типов:

```
foreach (var actTab in ActTabs)
{
    if (actTab is IDisposable myObj)
    {
       myObj.Dispose();       
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Можно лаконично через LINQ вызвать:

```
list.OfType<IDisposable>().ToList().ForEach(x=>x.Dispose());
```